# How to 'remove a model' from hasMany() association

Tags: sequelize.js, postman

I am following the offical Sequelizer docs, but I am unable to get it working with multiple "hasMany" associations.

I want to show only total employee not whole project resources model in postman when using `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()` association using sequelize, node js and express

How is this done correctly?

```js
Project.hasMany(projectResource, {foreignKey: 'projectId', sourceKey: 'id'}),  
projectResource.belongsTo(Project, {foreignKey: 'projectId', targetKey: 'id'})  

many(request)
{
    return Project.findAll({
        where: request,
        attributes: {
            include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("projectId")), "totalEmployee"]]
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: projectResource
          }
        ],
        group: ['Project.id']
    })
}
```

In postman I get

```js
"project": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "projectName": "enuke",
                "projectManagerId": 2,
                "projectType": "2",
                "status": "3",
                "startDate": "2019-06-18",
                "endDate": "2019-06-29",
                "createdAt": null,
                "updatedAt": "2019-06-19T06:57:57.000Z",
                "deletedAt": null,
                "totalEmployee": 1,
                "projectresources": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "projectId": 1,
                        "employeeId": 2,
                        "createdAt": "2019-06-20T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2019-06-20T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "deletedAt": null
                    }
                ]
            }]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Project.hasMany(projectResource, {foreignKey: 'projectId', sourceKey: 'id'}),  
projectResource.belongsTo(Project, {foreignKey: 'projectId', targetKey: 'id'})  

many(request)
{
    return Project.findAll({
        where: request,
        attributes: {
            include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("projectId")), "totalEmployee"]]
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: projectResource,
            attributes: [],
          }
        ],
        group: ['Project.id']
    })
}
```

can you please try this